# How to render partial view from another controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have partial view that is search form.That partial view have sportSectionController. I have other views that have other controllers. My question is how to render that partial view in that others views that have different controllers? Because i cant emit on every controller or to call table or something like that on every view...it does not make sense? So it should be on one place and it called from different places....Any suggestion?Maybe service or something like that?

EDIT:
I have offer content that is have sportOfferContentController and there i have partial views if something is wrong or not found but problem is now that i can call them only from `sportOfferContentController` i want to be able to call them from other controllers

Comment: Sounds like you want to make reusable directives that have their own templates and can be inserted anywhere in the app. Question is a bit hard to interpret. An example using simple html structure would help

Comment: @charlietfl see my update...do u need more information?